# Looping over array of objects in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I am trying to find the sum of all likes. The error I am getting is posts doesn't exist. User is an object with posts property, which is an array of objects. How would I access the likes property. Thanks

```
var sum = 0; //initialize sum
    //create user object
    var user = {
        posts: [
          {
           likes: 10
         }
          {
           likes: 15
         }

    ]
    }
    //Getting the sum of all likes. But doesn't work.
    for(i = 0; i < posts.length; i++) {
        sum += user.posts[i].likes;
    }
    return sum;
```

Comment: `i < user.posts.length` ?

Comment: Thnks. I was accessing the array in a wrong way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) can be used for easier aggregation:

```js
var user = { posts: [ { likes: 10 }, { likes: 15 } ] }

var sum = user.posts.reduce((s, o) => s + o.likes, 0)

console.log(sum)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is correct code:

```
var sum = 0; //initialize sum
//create user object
var user = {
    posts: [{
            likes: 10
        },
        {
            likes: 15
        }

    ]
}
//Getting the sum of all likes. But doesn't work.
for (var i = 0; i < user.posts.length; i++) {
    sum += user.posts[i].likes;
}
console.log(sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access object property like this `posts.length` it would throw you `undefined`, you need to use `user.posts.length`:

```
for(var i=; i<user.posts.length; i++){
  sum += user.posts[i].likes;
}
return sum;
```

Answer (score 0):

Something simpler instead of function

```js
var sum = 0;
var user = {
    posts: [
      {
       likes: 10
     },
      {
       likes: 15
     }

]
}

user["posts"].map(ele => sum=+ele["likes"]);
console.log(sum);
```